# Hyperledger Fabric - Peer unable to connect to (raft) Orderer with Mutual TLS

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running a HLF on kubernetes - (3 raft orderers & 2 peers)

Now as raft requires Mutual TLS I had to setup some certificates.

The 3 raft orderers are able to communicate with eachother, as they are electing a leader, and re-electing another leader when I bring that leader down.

When I setup the peer, I used the same CA to generate the certificates. I am able to create the channel & join it from the peer. However I have to run `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$ADMIN_MSP_PATH` prior to those commands, otherwise I get Access Denied error.

I am also forced to append the following flags to every `peer channel x` command I run.

```
--tls --cafile $ORD_TLS_PATH/cacert.pem --certfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE --keyfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE --clientauth
```

I am able to create, fetch, join the channel using the admin msp.

Now once the channel is joined, the peer is unable to connect with the orderer, somehow a bad certificate is given.

**Orderer Logs**

A bad certificate is used ?

```
2019-08-15 16:07:55.699 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 221 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=10.130.2.148:53922
2019-08-15 16:07:55.699 UTC [grpc] handleRawConn -> DEBU 222 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.130.2.148:53922": remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

***Peer Logs***

These suggest that it could not validate it with the ca.crt ?

```
2019-08-15 16:10:17.990 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03a parsed scheme: ""
2019-08-15 16:10:17.990 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03b scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-08-15 16:10:17.991 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03c ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-08-15 16:10:17.991 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03d ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-08-15 16:10:17.991 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00260b710, CONNECTING
2019-08-15 16:10:18.009 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 03f grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Reconnecting...
2019-08-15 16:10:18.012 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 040 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00260b710, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2019-08-15 16:10:18.991 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00260b710, CONNECTING
2019-08-15 16:10:19.003 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 042 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Reconnecting...
2019-08-15 16:10:19.003 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 043 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00260b710, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2019-08-15 16:10:20.719 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 044 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00260b710, CONNECTING
2019-08-15 16:10:20.731 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 045 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Reconnecting...
2019-08-15 16:10:20.733 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 046 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00260b710, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2019-08-15 16:10:20.990 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 047 Failed connecting to {orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 [OrdererMSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
```

I generated the used certificates as follows:

***Orderer Admin***

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://u:p@ca.example.com -M ./OrdererMSP
```

***Orderer Node X***

As I use the same certificates for TLS I added the used hosts here for TLS purposes

- orderer-x.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local #kubernetes
- orderer-x.hlf-orderers #kubernetes
- orderer-x #kubernetes
- localhost #local debug

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -m orderer-x \
  -u https://ox:px@ca.example.com \
  --csr.hosts orderer-x.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local,orderer-x.hlf-orderers,orderer-x,localhost \
  -M orderer-x-MSP
```

***Peer Admin***

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://u:p@ca.example.com -M ./PeerMSP
```

***Peer Node X***

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -m peer-x \
  -u https://ox:px@ca.example.com \
  --csr.hosts peer-x.hlf-peers.svc.cluster.local,peer-x.hlf-peers,peer-x,localhost \
  -M peer-x-MSP
```

Now all of these, have the same ca.crt (/cacerts/ca.example.com.pem)

**configtx.yaml**

```
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                    - Host: orderer-1.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: orderer-1-MSP/signcerts/cert.pem
                      ServerTLSCert: orderer-1-MSP/signcerts/cert.pem
                    - Host: orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: orderer-2-MSP/signcerts/cert.pem
                      ServerTLSCert: orderer-2-MSP/signcerts/cert.pem
                    - Host: orderer-3.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: orderer-3-MSP/signcerts/cert.pem
                      ServerTLSCert: orderer-3-MSP/signcerts/cert.pem
            Addresses:
                - orderer-1.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050
                - orderer-2.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050
                - orderer-3.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050
```

I have checked multiple times if the correct certificates are mounted on the correct places and configured.

On the peer side I made sure that:

- `CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES` is set correctly and that the (correct) file gets mounted (CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES: "/var/hyperledger/tls/client/cert/ca.crt")
- Idem for `CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE` & `CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE`
- `CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED` is set to true

On the orderer side I made sure that:

- `ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED` is set to true
- `ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE` is set correctly
- `ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY` is set correctly
- `ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS` is set correctly

It seems strange to me that the orderers are able to talk to eachother (as they are electing leaders), but that the peer is not able to do so

Comment: So, I disabled Client Auth on both sides - I still get the same error

Comment: I am able to 'force' the error manually, when running any command with `peer channel x --tls --cafile <WRONG-CA-FILE>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it appears to be, that the tlscacerts should be in the msp(s) directory(ies) `PRIOR` to creating genesis / channel block. Simply mounting them in the pod at runtime is not enough

My msp directories (used in configtx.yaml) look like:

- admincerts
- tlscacerts
- cacerts
- ...

After this it all started to work

Comment: does this mean the MSPDir section of configtx has to be configured for admincerts/tlscacerts/cacerts? I can't find an example of how this is configured online.

Comment: Well, as i'm using fabric-ca-client to create certificates, I have 1 directory with the client profile & 1 with the tls profile. As you point to the msp (client profile) directory in the configtx, this 'msp' directory should also contain the tlscacerts / admincerts / ... etc.. before creating genesis / channel

Comment: I am hitting the exact error as your original question now, however i am using configtxgen to create certificates. the generate.sh script creates the crypto material (organisation certs), the orderer genesis block, and then the channel. So it seems in the right order to me. Do you have any recommendations on what might need to change to match this answer? thx

Comment: could you please share your configtx.yaml file and the msp directory structure at the orderer and peer. I am facing similar issue of `TRANSIENT FAILURE`. I already have admincerts and tlscacerts populated before generating channel artifacts. My network is mutual TLS anabled.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you have got below error

```
E0923 16:30:14.963567129 31166 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate.
E0923 16:30:15.964456710 31166 ssl_transport_security.cc:188] ssl_info_callback: error occured.
```

According to your details, All seems to be correct
However check below

```
certificate signed by unknown authority -> This makes me bit doubt on your certificate mapping
```

**MAKE SURE**

---

PEER:

- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/tls/server.crt
- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/tls/server.key
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/data/maersksea-rca-maersksea-chain.pem
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/data/tls/maersksea-peer-maersksea-client.crt
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/data/tls/maersksea-peer-maersksea-client.key
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES=/data/maersksea-rca-maersksea-chain.pem

Orderer:

- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[/data/maersksea-rca-maersksea-chain.pem]

Comment: theres another example here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric-test/master/feature/docker-compose/docker-compose-solo.yml

Comment: I checked it like 100 times now, that can't be it. Every variable is set correctly and file mounted correctly

Comment: Also I am able to run this command correctly: `peer channel fetch config \
     /var/hyperledger/mychannel.block -c mychannel \
     -o orderer-1.hlf-orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 \
     --tls --cafile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES --certfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE --keyfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE --clientauth`

Comment: Which suggests that the variables are set and that the certificates are OK, it just looks like the internals of the peer, either don't use those variables, or that the hostname might be different ?